# Why did journal subscription prices increase by 25% between 2013 and 2017? (vs. 5% for US inflation)

Tags: journals, fees

I read on https://journals.ebsco.com/products-services/explore-content :

[image]

Why did journal subscription prices increase by 25% between 2013 and 2017?

That's much more than the US inflation ([~5.1%  between 2013 and 2017](http://www.in2013dollars.com/2013-dollars-in-2017) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171008191248/http://www.in2013dollars.com/2013-dollars-in-2017))):

[image]

(source of the image: http://www.usinflationcalculator.com/inflation/current-inflation-rates/  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171008191228/http://www.usinflationcalculator.com/inflation/current-inflation-rates/)))

Comment: Three words: because they can.

Comment: ^^^ Journals have an effective monopoly on intellectual dissemination. Authors want to publish in the "best" journal in their field and publishers will bundle 99 non-best journals in with the best journal to sell to libraries, which have no choice but to purchase the bundle.

Comment: Sci-hub. They lost so much money due to sci-hub, they just had to increase their prices.

Comment: @Mark Is it true? Probably, most of their revenues come from institutional subscriptions, and I doubt that these have been significantly affected by sci-hub.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I don't think so, but they said so. "Elsevier gave the court a list of 100 articles illicitly made available by Sci-Hub and LibGen, and asked for a permanent injunction and damages totalling $15 million" (https://www.nature.com/news/us-court-grants-elsevier-millions-in-damages-from-sci-hub-1.22196). But then, many people who use sci-hub do so because it's easier than going through their institutional subscription. Hence my view that they didn't lose anything.

Comment: On a more serious note: are there any numbers on the differences in earnings through open-access and (classic) paywall papers? The former gives a one-time big financial boost, the latter relies on "small" fees every time someone wants to access the paper (and cannot get it through institutional subscriptions).

Comment: @Mark: Elsevier presumably said so because it sounds better than "because we can get away with it".

Comment: Why shouldn't they? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJOjTNuuEVw

Comment: @Mark Let's ask: [Earnings generated by open-access papers vs. (classic) paywalled papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/97081/452)

Comment: Did you read the 2018 Serials Price Projection Report on the same page where you found this graph?  That says quite a bit about increasing journal prices.

Answer (score 7):

The direct answer is "because they can". Demand for journals is pretty inelastic - increasing the price doesn't cause much of a fall in demand. Can you imagine your university not subscribing to a journal like *The Lancet* or *Science*?

Behind that answer however is a storm of interlinked factors. Here're some of them:

1. Publishers are under pressure from their shareholders to show revenue and income growth. This is no different from university administrators pressuring their faculty to show research output growth, university ranking growth, and so on.
2. [The total number of academic papers being published worldwide is increasing quickly](http://blogs.nature.com/news/2014/05/global-scientific-output-doubles-every-nine-years.html). To shareholders this sounds like an excellent opportunity for growth! But not all these papers can be published in top journals, so a lot of them end up in not-so-good journals.
3. Most of the papers in these not-so-good journals are actually very seldom used. For example take the Elsevier journal [Wave Motion](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/wave-motion/). It's got an impact factor of 1.575, which is pretty medium. I picked a random paper, "An elastodynamic computational time-reversal method for shape reconstruction of traction-free scatterers", Vol 72, page 23-40, July 2017. Then I went to Web of Science, found the paper, and checked the usage statistics. Guess how many times it's been used in the past 180 days - three times (!).
4. Since the usage is so low, libraries are incentivized not to subscribe (and remember, this is a solidly middle-of-the-road journal - imagine what it's like for the bottom-tier ones). But if libraries don't subscribe, the journal makes a loss. What is the publisher to do?
5. Let's take the obvious thing to do, and one commonly argued for, which is to close the journal. If publishers did this *en masse*, there'd suddenly be no more journals except the few top-tier ones. Remember that the papers published in these not-so-good journals aren't necessarily bad - they're usually just rather boring, low-novelty papers: the backbone of science. Without the journals, these papers would never be published.
6. Another thing about these not-so-good journals is that they're crucial to researchers from developing countries. It's true that these researchers might be slightly less capable than those in developed countries, but it's also probable that they simply have fewer resources. If one is not able to access the Large Hadron Collider, one is also not likely to make breakthroughs in particle physics. Hence one ends up with boring, low-novelty papers that won't make it to top journals.
7. On top of all that, let's add the fact that some academics think that they write papers, they edit journals, they serve as reviewers, they deserve to be paid for it. I'm not saying that they're wrong, but you can see the tension this belief causes.

And then there's open access. Most forms of OA ties the revenue to the number of papers published (there are other models, but those journals are loss-making and only stay afloat because of an external source of funding). This means there's an immediate conflict of interest for the publisher, which is why there's predatory OA publishing, and in turn is why there's a backlash against OA. Also consider what it's like from the publisher's and library's points of view.

1. *Publisher*. If you convert a journal to OA, you're giving up subscription revenue. A bird in hand is worth two in the bush. Further, many academics prefer to publish in subscription journals even if they have access to OA funding, since if they publish OA they have to jump through some administrative hoops. There're also lots of academics in developing countries that simply cannot pay for OA. There's no guarantee that your 100-papers/year journal will still be 100-papers/year after you convert to OA. Do you dare? Remember your job is on the line (see comment above about shareholders).
2. *Library*. OA costs money. You need to free up funds somewhere to fund OA. In theory you should be able to use subscription money to pay for OA, but in practice, you're either subscribed to a journal or not. You can't just pay $3000 less for a subscription and use that for OA for a single article. The only way is to unsubscribe, which effectively removes access to every paper in the journal.

Finally, let's not forget that [publishing is a notoriously poorly-paid job](https://www.chronicle.com/article/The-Realities-of-Jobs-in/44665), and the publisher also has to keep its employees happy.

tl; dr: it's a difficult world out there. If you have a solution, you'd be in contention to win the Nobel Prize in Publishing.

Comment: This whole answer (it is so obvious that it may benefit from being pointed out) assumes a capitalistic way of publishing from the beginning to the end. Not all journals are published by companies with shareholders who seek to maximize profits.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I visited my university's press a few months ago. We touched a bit on profits - turns out their net margin was -50%, and they only remain afloat because of funding from the university.

Comment: Yes. What is your point? Commercial publishers only remain afloat thanks to the indirect subsidies by the universities (and if they're public, in the end it's the taxpayer) called "subscription costs" and/or "OA fees". The only difference is that the universities get no say in the amount of subsidies or how they are used – what's the net margin of a commercial publisher?

Comment: Certainly nothing we should be discussing in comments. I won't say any more, other than if you have a better model to handle academic publishing, you can try starting your own journal or publisher. As for net margin of commercial publishers, Wiley, Elsevier, etc are publicly held companies. You can check their annual reports.

Comment: ...you have already mentioned another model when you talked about your university's press. And my last question was obviously rhetorical. In case it's not clear, I'm pointing out that your answer is incomplete and only covers a part of all publishers and journals.

Comment: If you can write a supplemental answer filling in the blanks in mine, I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : "This whole answer […] assumes a capitalistic way of publishing" Indeed, but I guess it still answers the question properly, as the alternatives I know of to this way of publishing do not use subscription (free access through on-line archives, typically), and hence do not play any role in the increase of the subscription prices.

Comment: @Clément Try to access an article from Cambridge University Press or some AMS journals (these are just examples off the top of my head) without having a subscription. It's also a bit weird to think that having competitors who offer the same service "for free" (or financed indirectly) does not play any role in the final price asked by a company.

Comment: @Allure My criticism is invalid because I haven't written a complementary answer? That's a strange way of seeing things.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I don't think Allure is saying that your criticism is invalid, he's saying that it can't be developed in comments, and I agree with him. I agree with your remark that journals published for free can play a role in the price of subscriptions, I was short-sighted, but I still believe that it is a minor role compared to the role played by greed.

Comment: @Clément *I don't think Allure is saying that your criticism is invalid* Yes, precisely. Instead, they dismiss it for unrelated reasons – that I haven't written a complementary answer and thus cannot possibly know what I'm talking about. It's a basic rhetorical stratagem.

Comment: _Since OA ties the revenue to the number of papers published,_ not always. There are lots of so-called "Diamond OA" journals that don't charge authors or readers.

Comment: @DavidRoberts not really, relatively speaking there are very few such diamond OA journals. Since they don't charge authors *and* readers, they need external funding. They also don't offer typical publisher services such as copyediting (of course, the authors from first-world countries indulging in these diamond OA journals don't think they need it, but there are a lot of authors from non-English countries that do) and marketing. Finally these diamond OA journals don't scale well - see comments by Paul Ginsparg and Dan Kulp here: https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/201602/arxiv.cfm

Comment: @Allure "very few such diamond OA journals" - not according to DOAJ _A 2013 study found that only 28% of journals in the Directory of Open Access Journals (DOAJ) required payment by the authors; however, this figure was higher in journals with a scientific or medical focus (43% and 47% respectively), and lowest in journals publishing in the arts and humanities (0% and 4% respectively)_ (from WP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access_journal#No-fee_open_access_journals and citation is given as https://doi.org/10.1002%2Fasi.22972) and there are more recent figures than this

Comment: @Allure if you are thinking about volume of papers, then of course, that's slightly different. For detailed analysis I refer you to http://www.lulu.com/au/en/shop/walt-crawford/gold-open-access-journals-2011-2015/ebook/product-22758863.html (that's a free e-book) and data available here: https://waltcrawford.name/goaj.html

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for link. That's news to me, but I'm skeptical of the results. Eleven of the first twelve journals' website in the raw data did not load for me, and the sole one that did was not in English and did not look like a journal's website. Random attempts later in the dataset also led to a lot of dead links, and I only hit three journals' website. One was diamond OA but subsidized by a society, one charged 350,000 IDR, and one actually charged a subscription but called the journal "open access".

Comment: I'm mostly unconvinced I'm afraid. Diamond OA, if it's ever successful on a large scale, must simply shift the costs somewhere else. It might be a society, a publisher using its other activities to fund the diamond OA journal, or a university, but someone is paying for it. The people managing the journal must still put food on the table after all. It seems probable that the ultimate payer is still authors (in the form of membership fees to societies), universities, etc. Also we're way outside the scope of the comments section. If you want to discuss this somewhere else, I'm in.

Comment: @Allure I don't disagree about the cost of publishing and the scalability of Diamond OA. Just wanted to correct the idea that OA publishing = author pays, and give a sense of the scale of how many journals don't fit that mould. The main specialist journal in my subfield is Diamond OA and has been so for over 20 years. It's well regarded, so it's not a new concept for me. I think we had better not chat too much, either. :-)

Comment: A fair objection. I'll see how I can edit the answer.

Comment: If we read the question not as "why is there an increase in price" but rather "why is the increase in prices occurring now?", is this answer basically saying "since there are more people wanting to publish, there is an increase in demand?  Regardless of how the supply curve looks, it seems possible to me that the increase in demand is so much so as to increase prices a lot, but this would be stronger if the supply curve were also inelastic...